# Show uiimagepicker at full screen on the ipad, with an Unity plugin

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, fullscreen, unity-game-engine

I have using a plugin to show an UIImagepickercontroller as a subview in my iphone/ipod app. In iPad i get an error that says i should use a popover instead. I'm using my own custom plugin in unity.

The popover works...but the size is too small, i would like to have a consistant experience and show the picker at full screen in the iphone as well.

It's possible to show the UIImagepicker at full screen in the iPad ?, or at least to force a bigger size for the popover ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is, and if you manage to hack it, I don't think it increases your chances of getting app store approval.

You can build your own custom interface to access photos. Have a look at `ALAssetsLibrary`.